# como agregar classlist a un solo objeto de un array Javascript NO jquery

Tags: javascript

```
const querys = document.querySelectorAll('.high');

const HandleClick = () => {
  const arrayLi = Array.from(querys);
  const active = arrayLi.find((cv) => cv.classList.contains('active'));
  arrayLi.forEach((li) => {
    if(!li.classList.contains('active')) {
      li.classList.add('active');
    } else if (li.classList.contains('active')) {
      li.classList.remove('active');
    }
  })
    
}

querys.forEach((query)=> {
  query.addEventListener('click', HandleClick)
})
```

necesito que la clase active se agrege solo al elemento que se hace click y no a todos los elementos del array de objetos P

Comment: y que as intentando hasta ahora porque en el codigo esta la respuesta... tambien puedes investigar acerca de `event.target`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, ahí me he puesto a investigar y ya estoy cerca de la solución que buscaba!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checa esta modificacion de tu codigo:

```js
const querys = document.querySelectorAll('.high');

function HandleClick(ev){
  ev.target.classList.toggle("active");
}

querys.forEach(query => query.addEventListener('click', HandleClick));
```

Usa el metodo `toggle` para cuando requieras añadir una clase solo cuando no se encuentre en el elemento, esta misma funcion hara lo contrario (remover) la clase si ya se encuentra.

Tambien recuerda que al pasarle un callback a un `addEventListener`, automaticamente se le pasa al callback un parametro, en este caso un evento, este evento tiene unas propiedades o metodos, la que nos interesa es `target` ya que esta nos devuelve el elemento en si el cual se disparo por medio del evento.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Estoy probando la función que me has pasado. Esta perfecto, pero no se bien como hacer para que haya solo un botón activo. Es decir si estoy en botón A activo y aprieto el B que el A deje de estar activo. No se que parametros tomar para hacer el condicional.

Comment: Recuerda que si mi respuesta fue de ayuda o soluciono tu problema puedes darle click al boton que parece un chulo abajo de mis votos para darla como aceptada.